# Life on the planet of an F-type star

Tags: planets

What will vegetation, weather and sea colour be like on a planet of an [F type star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star)? Assuming that the conditions are similar to Earth. (Enough ozone layer etc)

The intelligent beings travelled there so they don't need a star with a longer life.

Answer (score 7):

F type stars are very similar to G-type stars, except they are a bit brighter(irrelevant, the planet just orbits further out), and the spectrum is shifted up a bit.

G-type stars emissions peak at about 450nm , whereas F-type stars peak at something like 400nm.

So your "white" light from the F-type star will be a bit bluer. (actually just even more violet than our star G-type is). As you have stipulated thick enough ozone, this is almost completely irrelevant. The light that reaches the surface will be very, very similar. The visual appearance of the sun will be a light source similar in total power to our sun, but smaller, bluer and more intense. About the visual difference between a modern bright LED room light, and an older incandescent one of the same lumen output.

Weather: the upper atmosphere will absorb a larger fraction of the solar output. Your ozone layer will be working overtime. This should have almost zero effect on ground level weather.

The *main* difference between and F and G type star is that the F-type burns brighter, uses up its fuel in 1/5th of the time. 2-3 billion years, compared to the ~10 billion years a G-type gets. So life , if it develops under an F, had better get its act together and *fast*, or it will run out of sun before it figures out how to grow lungs. Earth life took longer than an F-type would provide, already.

Comment: There's a bit of a spectrum between F0 and F9 stars... at the top end the peak is at ~380nm and ~13% of the stellar output is UV (vs 4% for Sol). That extra UV is potentially problematic for atmosphere retention (more high-altitude photolysis -> more monatomic gas in the upper atmosphere => higher losses via Jeans escape) though modelling quite how bad isn't something I'm able to do. An F9 star by contrast isn't much more problematic than a slightly hotter Sun (and Venus might have been OK, prior to the volcanic incident).

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes more UV means faster atmosphere loss. Is this increased loss rate proportional to the vastly reduced potential lifespan of the planet? Even if the loss rate is 5X higher, the planet will lose less atmosphere over the life of the star, compared to our boring G2

Answer (score 4):

It is close enough to Earth and Sol that it can be whatever your story requires.  Tortoises and whelks, yes.

> What’s the good of a plan that ain’t no more trouble than that? It’s
> as mild as goose-milk. Why, Huck, it wouldn’t make no more talk than
> breaking into a soap factory. - [Tom Sawyer, from Adventures of Huckleberry Finn](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/21/the-adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/214/chapter-34/)

Tom has a point.  Ho.  Hum.  Instead:

**Tidally locked chthonian planet!**

This hot jupiter has had its hydrogen and helium blown away from staring its Sun in the eye.  What is left is the heavier gases and a water ocean: the Great Chthon!

Plants are chemotrophs because it is too hot on the sunny side for life.  Light on the dark side is reflected from the clouds and from its several phenomenally bright moons so the sky is dark.  Energy for the plants is chemical energy, formed by the riot of reactions on the hot side - pretty much every kind of combination the atmospheric gases can make gets made under the blast of light.
These molecules are then carried with the perpetual high winds of this planet to the dark side.

Nearly everything is underwater because of the high winds.  The different plants specialize in different chemicals - some reducing cyanide, some hydrogenating acetylene with water.  All have in common large surface areas to maximize their ability to capture nutrition blowing in from the hot side.  Some plants extend up above the water to gain an edge on their subsurface competetion and then lose these dispensable suprasurface appendages to the frequent storms - if not the wind, then the lightning.  The farther you are from the terminator the larger these plants get because the currents get weaker as you approach the dark pole.   T

These plants are a riot of vivid colors to our eyes because of their protective compounds - herbivores are everywhere.  Animal life feeds among the plants and there are fliers which avoid the larger water predators and cruise along looking for their favorite feed.  These might perch on the plants which extend up out of the water.  They can tell when a storm is coming and try to outrun it, or hunker down under the surface until trouble passes.

Moonlight is bright on this world and there are 3 moons to provide it.  On a moonless day the only natural colors are short frequencies that can scatter back from the sky - blue, indigo, violet and ultraviolet.  Under the surface it gets dark fast and many creatures make their own light, like residents of our own deep seas - and for the same reasons: communication with their own kind, attraction of prey, defense from predation, camouflage against a relatively brighter sky.  The bioluminescents come in all colors.  Plant equivalents on the dark side make their own light to attract pollinators.  To a human eye, the dark side is all blinking lights: Vegas from the air by night.

But work out before you go because gravity is 4x Earth gravity, and wear your goggles because the wind is no joke.

> ...I knowed mighty well that whenever he got HIS plan ready it
> wouldn’t have none of them objections to it.
>
> And it didn’t. He told me what it was, and I see in a minute it was
> worth fifteen of mine for style, and would make Jim just as free a man
> as mine would, and maybe get us all killed besides.

[Adventures of Huckleberry Finn](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/21/the-adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/214/chapter-34/)

Comment: A planet orbiting an F type star that is tidally locked is more than likely very toasty. Even Mercury in our own system isnt completely tidally locked. This world you talk about would have to orbit closer to a hotter star than Mercury in our own. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon_Andromedae_d is a good example of a gas giant orbiting an F-type star in the habitable zone

Comment: @Sonvar - I here assert this planet is extremely cloudy, left over from its gas giant days.     The clouds reflect and .. insulate!  Yeah, that is what they totally do.

Comment: Not sure the reflectiveness of water vapor is up to the task when the upper atmosphere is 4000 kelvin.

Answer (score 0):

The sea color would appear about the same. The light output of the star would make everything look more whiter and brighter. Tropical sea may look sharper and more deeper turquoise, but it should be fairly the same.

With increased solar output, more energy per square meter would be deposited to the ocean surfaces. This should increase the rate of water evaporation, thus more clouds and possibly more rain in areas, while the deserts will be more brutal. To keep an atmosphere longer term, it may have a thicker atmosphere.

About vegetation, it took life around 1.5 billion years to develop land plant life more complex than slime mosses and algae. as @pcman stated, the stars average life cycle being 2-3 billion years, if you came to this world late in its life you may get more complex life.

So, if you came there in the equivalent of the carboniferous period (which may not even exist due to not enough time to evolve), you will have basal trees, tall and lanky, all vying for light. With increased solar energy and higher UV output, the leaves may be larger, thicker and more leathery to survive damage from UV light. With higher energy output, it may not need to have as much chloroplast to get the energy it needs. Plus it could help reflect some harmful excess light energy being lighter in color.

More than likely, your life would be restricted to the seas, being fairly simple forms of life as not enough time to evolve would be allotted on this world. More than likely, your world would be restricted to the development of no later than the early Paleoproterozoic period. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleoproterozoic